# Need to get multiple lines from a text file and compare to a sentence

Tags: php

I wrote PHP code that checks if a word is in a sentence or not.

I've written this code:

```
<?php 
$text = "I go to school";
$word = file_get_contents("bad.txt");
if (strpos($text,$word)) {
    echo 'true';
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work because the txt file look like this:

```
test
hola
owb
```

How can I make the code check the words on each line against the sentence instead of one line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to check each line at a time, like so:

```
$text = "I go to school";
$file = file("bad.txt");

foreach($file as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $text) !== false) {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Edit1: file_get_content() to file()

Edit2: swap the paramaters of strpos()

Edit3: use:
    strpos($line, $text) !== false

Edit4: I see I've misunderstood the question. You want to check if the input contains any of the words stored in the file (instead of the other way around as I had assumed).

Try this:

```
$text = $_GET['name'];
$file = file("bad.txt");

foreach($file as $line) {
    if (strpos($text, $line) !== false) {
        echo 'Found';
        exit;
    }
}
echo 'Not Found';
```

Edit5: Turns out the '\n' control character is included in the line. so you need to use strpos($text, trim($line) !== false).

```
$text = $_GET['name'];
$file = file("bad.txt");

foreach($file as $line) {
    if (strpos($text, trim($line)) !== false) {
        echo 'Found';
        exit;
    }
}
echo 'Not Found';
```

Comment: My mistake, check the edited post, use file() instead of file_get_contents()

Comment: @tryharder. For this solution to work, replace `file_get\contents()` by `file()` to get an array of lines. On the other hand, don't only write `if (strpos($text, $line))` but `if (strpos($text, $line) === TRUE)`, or a word won't be recognized if at pos 0 in text.

Comment: but guys , i've choosed to get the sentence via GET request as in this code 
<?php 
$text = $_GET["name"];
$file = file("bad.txt");

foreach($file as $line) {
    if (strpos($text, $line)) {
        echo 'true';
    }
}

?>

but it seems not work , is there idea ?

Comment: In strpos($text, $line), you need to swap the parameters to strpos($line, $text). Also, for the if statement use if(strpos($line, $text) !== false) {...}

Comment: i've tested your code 

<?php 
$text = "I go to school";
$file = file("bad.txt");

foreach($file as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $text) !== false) {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
?>


and seem not working !

the txt file is :
go
hi
hello

Comment: The code works for me. Are you sure the file 'bad.txt' exists in the current directory? You could try printing each line of the file to make sure that it's being read in correctly.  Other than that I can't help much more.

Comment: MAY I ask you , for this one , 
<?php 
 $text = $_GET["name"];
 $file = file("bad.txt"); 
 foreach($file as $line) { 
if (strpos($text, $line)) { 
echo 'true'; } } 
?>
 

why the GET request not working ?

Comment: It will work if your request is something like http://example.com/myscript.php?name=john

You also still need to swap strpos($text, $line) to strpos($line, $text)

Comment: excatly that's what i do , but nothing i don't see any true Statment ! , even the words in the txt file :( Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Are you getting that foreach error with 'foreach($file as $line)' ? Which version of php are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.2.6 this my php version

Comment: may i ask you to make a code for check if the  bad word exitis in the sentence of GET REQUEST , and the bad word would be into txt file like 
hi
hi 
Hi

and if this available show fouond and if not Show not found ?

Comment: Now your code works well ! , just one error , if i had txt file like 
mek
jhjh
jhgj
hola
friend


and i write http://localhost/ok.php?name=friend
it's Gave me "Found " and this Good , 
but if i write http://localhost/ok.php?name=hola

it's gave me "not found " what's the problem ? why he check the last line of file only ?

Comment: PRoblem solved , but what if instead echo not found , add the string into the same txt file in new line and the next also be in new line what about that ?

Comment: Since this answers the question as asked, could you accept my answer? As for this request I don't understand what you're asking for. Could you clarify? perhaps it would be best for another question.

Comment: Done , i mean i want if the words that already checked in the code and user get message this word not found in Bad words list , I want to add code to write this word into bad words list in new line

Comment: You could add this line after "echo 'Not Found';",  "
file_put_contents('bad.txt', $text . "\n", FILE_APPEND);"